# WebSphere is not displaying webpage element when url contains string "?error "

Tags: java, spring-security, websphere, websphere-8

I am working on a Spring security project where if User inserts wrong userId - password, webpage will update with "Invalid Login Attempt" message.

I am sending redirect on AuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure

code snippet for onAuthenticationFailure() implementation.

```
@Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
      //some logic
      response.sendRedirect(String.format("%s?error", getUrl());
    }
  }
```

Resource Html page has div tag with thymeleaf dependency to identify `error` object and display message

```
<div th:if="${error}" id="loginFailedMessage" class="alert alert-danger">
   Invalid login attempt.
</div>
```

So far this implementation **works on Jboss application server and WebLogic application server** - however when **not for websphere**. Is there a reason why WebSphere is blocking such url invocation - any configuration am I missing. I have tired different version of WebSphere 8.5.5.9 up to 8.5.5.13

ps. there are no errors in any logs ffdc or application logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution will be to use `error=true` in url. for some reason websphere does not allow url parameter without assigning values.

```
@Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
      //some logic
      response.sendRedirect(String.format("%s?error=true", getUrl());
    }
  }
```